# matplotlib circle, animation, how to remove old circle in animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to simulate an animation of a circular shock wave from a selected data point using Matplotlib's circle and animation. 
But I couldn't figure out a way to remove the older circles in every new frame. As a result, as the radius increases, I got more and more circles drawing on the canvas - like this:

[image]

Any advice on animating a circular shockwave on a matplotlib plot?

The code I have so far is :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

testData = np.random.rand(100,2)-[0.5, 0.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def init():
    fig.clf()
    sctPlot, = ax.plot(testData[:,0], testData[:,1], ".")

# i is the radius
def animate(i):
    init()
    q = 20 #initial index for the starting position
    pos = testData[q,:]
    circle1=plt.Circle(pos,i,color='r',fill=False, clip_on = False)
    fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)

def init():
    sctPlot, = ax.plot(testData[:,0], testData[:,1], ".")
    return sctPlot,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0.4, 2, 0.1), init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just use `set_radius` to change the circle size every time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


testData = np.random.rand(100,2)-[0.5, 0.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
circle1=plt.Circle(testData[20,:],0,color='r',fill=False, clip_on = False)
ax.add_artist(circle1)
# i is the radius
def animate(i):
    #init()
    #you don't want to redraw the same dots over and over again, do you?
    circle1.set_radius(i)


def init():
    sctPlot, = ax.plot(testData[:,0], testData[:,1], ".")
    return sctPlot,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0.4, 2, 0.1), init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

So you are not removing and redrawing patches every round, which I think may be more efficient.

Comment: thanks... set_radius is exactly what I need. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, again. The new code works fine but not on ipython notebook. It seems to crash the kernel. I used %pylab tk to pop out the plt window. Do you think it has something to do with this?

Comment: Might be a TK issue?  If you are not in ipython notebook it works?  I am using OSX backend and didn't get that problem at all.

Comment: Yes, it works in other places but not notebook.  What is your suggestion? I changed it to %pylab osx . But this won't result in a popped up window. Animation will not work on inplace (or inline?) on notebook.

Comment: Don't know.  :(. I am on OSX backend and the popped up works. I checked it by `%matplotlib` and it does return `Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your animate function:

```
for obj in ax.findobj(match = type(plt.Circle(1, 1))):
  obj.remove()
```

`ax.findobj(match = type(plt.Circle(1, 1)))` looks for all the circle patches on the axes, which you can then remove before plotting a new circle. I used `plt.Circle()` to make a circle object to match -- the arguments you pass it don't really matter.