# How to remove/update old animation lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Here my code stripped down to its bare minimal to correctly reproduce my problem.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os.path

f, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,10))

def animate(i):
    chosenEnergy = (0.0 + (i-1)*(0.02))
    chosenEnergyLine = ax2.axvline(float(chosenEnergy),0,1, linestyle='dashed')
    return chosenEnergyLine,

def init():
    chosenEnergyLine = ax2.axvline(0.0,0,1, linestyle='dashed')
    return chosenEnergyLine,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, np.arange(1,nE), init_func=init,
interval=25, blit=False, repeat = False)

plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg'
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()

ani.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer = FFwriter, fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
print "finished"
```

The problem is that I want to new vertical line (at a different energy) to replace the old line. Instead, the final frame shows all lines.

I found a similar question ([matplotlib circle, animation, how to remove old circle in animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013763/matplotlib-circle-animation-how-to-remove-old-circle-in-animation)), but does not seem to apply for my case.

Even if a similar function as the one used in the answer to this similar question (`set_radius`) exists for `xvline`, I'd prefer not to use it. In my other subplot (ax1), I have a scatter plot that will have to be updated each time. Is there a general way to clear the plot before the next time step?

I also didn't notice any change when using blit=False or blit=True.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `animate` you're drawing a new line. You should either delete the old lines, or move your line with `set_xdata` instead of drawing a new one.

```
def animate(i,chosenEnergyLine):
    chosenEnergy = (0.0 + (i-1)*(0.02))
    chosenEnergyLine.set_xdata([chosenEnergy, chosenEnergy])
    return chosenEnergyLine,

chosenEnergyLine = ax2.axvline(0.0,0,1, linestyle='dashed')
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, np.arange(1,10),
       fargs=(chosenEnergyLine,), interval=25, blit=False, repeat = False)
```

**UPDATE:** That's because you're trying to delete the same global `chosenEnergyLine` multiple times (`FuncAnimation` catches the return value of `animate` but it does not update the global `chosenEnergyLine` with it). The solution is to use kind of a static variable in animate to keep track of the latest `chosenEnergyLine`

```
def animate(i):
    chosenEnergy = (0.0 + (i-1)*(0.02))
    animate.chosenEnergyLine.remove()
    animate.chosenEnergyLine = ax2.axvline(float(chosenEnergy),0,1, linestyle='dashed')
    return animate.chosenEnergyLine,

animate.chosenEnergyLine = ax2.axvline(0.0,0,1, linestyle='dashed')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, np.arange(1,10),
                interval=25, blit=False, repeat = False)
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. And how about your other suggestion: deleting old lines (or scatter plots, etc)? That's probably more general and more useful for me, as I have other parts to my figure that have to updated at each step... I tried using `del` or obj.remove() functions inside the `animate` part, but couldn't make it work. Usually, it was complaining about the `chosenEnergyLine` object not existing.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Azad what happens if we have multiple lines but the quality will only be known as the next data point is processed?